# Is there a way for browser.tabs.sendMessage to all tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon

Currently, I have this in my background script:

```
function disable(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {
        command: "Disable"
        });
    }
}

else if (e.target.classList.contains("disable")) {
    browser.tabs.query({})
    .then(disable)
}
```

I have this in my content script:

```
(function () {
    
    if (window.hasRun) {
    return;
  }
    window.hasRun = true;

    function disableHelper() {
        clearInterval(Interval1)
        console.log("Helper has been disabled")
    }
        
    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
        if (message.command === "Blah") {
            var Interval1 = setInterval(changeToHelper, 15000);
            Interval1;
        } else if (message.command === "Disable") {
        disableHelper();
        }
    });
                        
})();
```

I have permissions set to only run this on sites with specified URLs and it works when the tab is in focus/active.

However, if I click "Disable" within my popup on another tab that is not part of the permissions it won't Disable properly on the desired tab.

Is there a way to 'sendMessage' to all tabs regardless if they're in focus/active?

Comment: The message is sent to all tabs regardless of focus, so the problem is in your content script.

Comment: Just edited in my content script as well

Comment: The intervals are throttled in inactive tabs to 1 per minute. Try moving setInterval to the background script, which will send messages accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but here you go.
You can send a message to all tabs by calling

```
//remove currentWindow:true if you want to add all the tabs across all windows
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({
  currentWindow: true
});
for (const tab of tabs) {
  if (!tab.id) continue;
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{type:"your message"})
  }
```